# Relationship is loaded but returns null when I call it

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I query a model 'Royalty' and eager load the relationship 'Owner'. The model returns the result, including the relationship.

```
class Royalty extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates   = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date', 'calculated_at'];

    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'object',
    ];

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Owner::class);
    }
}

class Owner extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates    = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'object',
    ];


    public function royalties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Royalty::class);
    }
}

$royalty = Royalty::with('owner')->where('id', 1)->first();
```

The result is as expected and the relationship 'owner' is eagerloaded:

```
Royalty {#542 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #dates: array:4 [▶]
  #casts: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "development"
  #table: "royalties"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:21 [▶]
  #original: array:21 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "owner" => Owner {#562 ▼
      #guarded: []
      #dates: array:4 [▶]
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "development"
      #table: "owners"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [▶]
      #original: array:8 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

However, when I call the relationship with $royalty->owner the result is NULL. What am I doing wrong here?

```
dd($royalty->owner); NULL
```

Comment: try `dd($royalty['owner'])`

Comment: also NULL when I do dd($royalty['owner'])

Comment: Can you provide code from your controller and table structure?

Comment: Extra info: when I try $owner = $royalty->owner()->first(); I get the owner as expected. So there seems to be nothing wrong with the relationship?

Comment: Does the `royalties` table have an `owner` column?

Comment: Yes the Royalties table has an owner_id column that references id in Owner table

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reason why this would happen.

- one is that the information in the database has changer
- You have overloaded the `toArray()` method in the model `Owner` (i know it's not in your example)

Comment: I can confirm that the database has NOT been changed. Also, I don't have any reference to toArray() in the Owner model....

Comment: have you tried removing the $cast attribute. `protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'object',
    ];`

Comment: Run a composer update, this is not normal behavior of illuminate/laravel

Comment: @Arjan any updates ? did you find the cause of this behavior

Comment: No, I did a composer update, but the issue is still there. Very strange, because it seems that some other relations with the Royalty model are working as normal.

Comment: @Arjan do you have a getOwnerAttribute on `Royalty::class` declared ?

Comment: No, do I need to?

Comment: @Arjan, no if you had one, that would explain why it's acting like that, or if you have overloaded the `__get` magic method on the model

Answer (score 0):

You must use fillable instead of guarded.

```
class Royalty extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'id', ...];
    protected $dates   = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'date', 'calculated_at'];

    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'object',
    ];

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Owner::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed from $guarded to $fillable with all columns. But the result is still NULL...

Comment: after fillable in your controller you must be write After query. dd($royalty);

Comment: When I do dd($royalty->owner) I still get NULL. However the Owner is available when I do dd($royalty)...

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your relatioship like this,
 In royalty model please define

`public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Owner::class,'owner_id');
    }` and take `id` as fillable in owner model.

And your

`public function royalties()
         {
        return $this->hasMany(Royalty::class);
        }` is perfect

Comment: @Arjan in your model you didn't specified any fillable columns atleast specify one fillable column to both models

Comment: I already change both models to protected $fillable = ['id'].

Still getting NULL while I can see that the relation is loaded...

Comment: @Arjan Not only `id` fill some data to a new column  like `name` or anything else

Comment: Added a few other columns. Still getting null!